# Can I use @Controller instead of @ManagedBean in JS managed bean in Webapplication using jsf integrated with spring

Tags: spring, jsf

Can I use `@Component` instead of `@ManagedBean` in managed bean Java class.
When I use `@ManagedBean` and use `@Autowired` annotation for a object in the ManagedBean, I get null value in the object. If I use `@Controller` I dont face this problem

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class OwnerListBean implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3237148505293593526L;

    OwnerService ownerService;

    public OwnerService getOwnerService() {
        return ownerService;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setOwnerService(OwnerService ownerService) {
        this.ownerService = ownerService;
    }
}
```

The above code works.

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class OwnerListBean implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3237148505293593526L;

    OwnerService ownerService;

    public OwnerService getOwnerService() {
        return ownerService;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setOwnerService(OwnerService ownerService) {
        this.ownerService = ownerService;
    }

}
```

In the above code the object `ownerService` is `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really reminds me of what happened when CDI/Weld was introduced into the core Java specification, and JSF already had its own implementation of dependency injection.  The two specs were essentially developed at the same time, and in isolation, causing significant functional overlap.

Initially, the answer was a framework called SEAM, which, as the name implied, was a kind of add-on to WELD, and which served the function of merging the CDI and JSF DI worlds. This project has been absorbed piece by piece into J2EE 7, JSF 2.2 and the Apache Deltaspike projects.

You're facing a similar problem here, and what you likely need to do is find or build a bridge between the JSF and Spring namespaces in a generic way. Otherwise, you'll just need to chose one or the other. Unless you REALLY need the JSF scopes, I'd highly recommend choosing the other (Spring) and even if you do need the JSF scopes, just reimplement them in Spring.

I prefer Weld personally, but I can't blame anyone for using the Spring ecosystem, it's very rich, and will almost certainly have a replacement for anything the JSF DI system will provide.

Comment: I have used spring scope. I have SpringBeanFacesELResolver which will take care of references to Spring beans in a ManagedBean.

Answer (score 0):

`@Autowired` is a Spring specific annotation. It only works in a Spring managed bean, i.e. a bean which is a `@Component` or `@Controller`.

Alternatively, you could use `@ManagedBean` with `@ManagedProperty`. By default, you can't define a Spring bean as a ManagedProperty. But Spring provides an integration to allow references to Spring beans in a ManagedBean: [SpringBeanFacesELResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/jsf/el/SpringBeanFacesELResolver.html)

Using this ELResolver, you should be able to do the following:

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class OwnerListBean implements Serializable{

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{ownerService}")
    OwnerService ownerService;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Will there be a problem with JSF if I use '@Component' instead of '@ManagedBean' and '@Autowired'.

Comment: If you are using `SpringBeanFacesELResolver` you will be able to reference the Spring bean from any EL expression in your JSF pages. But as SplinterReality explained, I would avoid to mix Spring and JSF managed beans together.